# Sanity in React: How can I fetch many students related to one project??? (Many authors to 1 Block)

Tags: sanity

I am working on a portfolio website in React using Sanity. The two components objects are students and projects. On the homepage, I can click on a link to a specific project, and this routes to another page showing the individual project. Furthermore, on this single page I would like to display all the students who have worked on this project. With sanity studio, I have created the necessary relations.

However, no matter on which project I click, it displays all students, no matter if they are related or not. I suspect that I am doing something wrong in my Sanity.fetch. This is from my SingleProject component where I want data about the project and the related students(One to many)

```
  .fetch(
    `*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
  title,
  _id,
  slug,
  mainImage{
    asset->{
      _id,
      url
    }
  },
  body,
  description,
  tags,
  "students": *[_type == "student" && project._ref in *[_type=="project" && title == title ]._id ]{
    name,
    mainImage{
      asset->{
        id,
        url
      }
    },
    "slug": slug.current,

  }
}`
```

This is from my project schema referencing the students from the student schema.

export default {
name: 'project',
title: 'Project',
type: 'document',
fields: [
{
title: 'Students',
name: 'students',
type: 'array',
of: [
{
type: 'reference',
to: [{ type: 'student' }],
},
],
},

I don't know why it fetches every student in the project component. Can somebody help?

Comment: I have seen the other post about authors and posts, but it did not give me the right answer. My projects are still taking every student, no matter if they have worked on it or not

Answer (score 0):

After long research, I have found the answer.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
      title,
      _id,
      slug,
      mainImage{
        asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      },
      body,
      description,
      tags,
      "projects": *[_type=='project' && references(^._id)]{
        title,
        mainImage{
          asset->{
            id,
            url
          }
        }
      },
        "slug": slug.current
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setSingleStudent(data[0]))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [slug]);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.